# Find true negatives in a confusion matrix

Tags: machine-learning, confusion-matrix, computational-statistics

I'm trying to find the True negative in a confusion matrix, I have computed successfully from scratch the precision and recall/sensibility, now i need to compute the accuracy and specificity.
This is my confusion Matrix:

[image: cm]

Computing the precision for 0 class

```
Precision=  TP*100/(TP+FP)
precision = 66*100/(66+2+0)
precision = 97.0588
```

Computing the precision for 1 class

```
Precision=  TP*100/(TP+FP)
precision = 81*100/(81+1+1)
precision = 97.5903
```

Computing the precision for 2 class

```
Precision=  TP*100/(TP+FP)
precision = 56*100/(56+3+0)
precision = 94.9152
```

Using the Pycm library I got:

```
PPV(Precision or positive predictive value) 0.97059  0.9759 0.94915
```

where 0.97059 is the precision for the class 0, and the next for 1 and the last for the 2 class.

Computing the recall for 0 class

```
recall =  TP*100/(TP+FN)
recall =  66/(66+2+0)
recall =  97.0588
```

Computing the recall for 1 class

```
recall =  TP*100/(TP+FN)
recall =  81/(81+2+3)
recall =  94.1860
```

Computing the recall for 2 class

```
recall =  TP*100/(TP+FN)
recall =  56/(56+0+1)
recall =  94.1860
```

Using Pycm library I got:

```
TPR(recall or true positive rate)  0.98507 0.94186  0.98246
```

where 0.98507 is the precision for the class 0, and the next for 1 and the last for the 2 class.

What happen now if I want to compute the accuracy? equation: Accuracy = (TP+TN)*100/(TP+TN+FP+FN) the equation is ok? I'm using the constant 100 to get the percent and not 0.x or 0.00xx but 90.x etc.

[image: accuracy equation]

I would like to know how I can get the True Negatives (TN) to compute the accuracy and specificity, currently using Pycm library I'm getting this values for the 3 classes:

```
ACC(Accuracy) 0.98571       0.96667       0.98095
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm one of the [PyCM](https://github.com/sepandhaghighi/pycm) developers.

1. Your `precision` calculation method is completely  correct.
2. For `recall` calculation you should consider improperly classified items in each row :

class 0 :

```
recall =  TP*100/(TP+FN)
recall =  66/(66+1+0)
recall =  98.5074
```

class 1 :

```
recall =  TP*100/(TP+FN)
recall =  81/(81+2+3)
recall =  94.1860
```

class 2 :

```
recall =  TP*100/(TP+FN)
recall =  56/(56+0+1)
recall =  98.2456
```

3. Accuracy formula is correct.
4. Finding TN for each class :

You should consider `class` vs `other` and add up items that classified correctly as `other`, in other words eliminate row and col related to `class` and add up remaining.

class 0 :

```
accuracy = (TP+TN)*100/(TP+TN+FN+FP)
accuracy = (66+141)/(66+141+2+1)
accuracy = 98.5714
```

class 1 :

```
accuracy = (TP+TN)*100/(TP+TN+FN+FP)
accuracy = (81+122)/(81+122+2+5)
accuracy = 96.6666
```

class 2 :

```
accuracy = (TP+TN)*100/(TP+TN+FN+FP)
accuracy = (56+150)/(56+150+1+3)
accuracy = 98.0952
```

Best Regards

Sepand Haghighi

Comment: Hi, Sepand thanks so much for your reply, really you made a great work creating PyCM library, it will help to us to minimize the time to evaluate machine learning models, however in my case I'm doing a thesis and "I need to do manual calculations" to demostrate to the jury.. anyways.. I would like to know why you don't you sum all the TP diag and then subtract  it with the TP of the actual class, I was doing that lately.. I find those trick here: https://bit.ly/2wyBtJ3 the Prof. Ahmad Hassanat said that. anyways I think that your method is more precise and is according with the PyCM library.

Comment: I read the link you mentioned above.
Prof. Ahmad Hassanat method about TN calculation is not correct. Because when you have a multi-class classification problem and want to calculate TN for each class you should consider confusion matrix in binary form (`class` and `other`) and any item that classified as `other` correctly (may incorrect as other classes) should be included in TN.

If you need more detail I'm available in Telegram by `sepkjaer` id.

Comment: Again I found one error in this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327148996_Classification_Assessment_Methods_a_detailed_tutorial Pag. 6 (2.9.2 (Multi-classification example) the author of that said that the FN are compute adding the col of the actual class, which is incorrect. The FP on there yes we use the col of the class but not for FN.

Comment: [This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327148996_Classification_Assessment_Methods_a_detailed_tutorial) method is true, you should consider transpose of matrix.